# Regular expression to match multiple strings with AND operator

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm developing an HTML parser. Specifically, I'm working on a module which parses PHP errors from the returned HTML. Here's an example:

```
PHP Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in   /local/www/example.com/includes/database/mysql/database.inc on line 43
```

To parse it, I want to search for `"fatal error" AND "on line"`. Can this be done with the `preg_match` regex? If so, how?

Comment: What parts of the string do you actually want to catch? Simply "Fatal error" and "on line" or the strings after them that would actually make any sense?

Comment: i wand catch "Fatal error" and "on line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/.*(Fatal error).+(on line).*/
```

will catch the strings "Fatal error" and "on line".

Answer (score 0):

Not so hard, have a look at txt2re.com to practically write a regular expressions without knowing anything about it!

Here's a starter for you

```
/Fatal error: (.*?) on line (\d+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to parse this at all with REGEX; it is already possible to pass the errors as `$variables`. You can specify your own error handler in PHP with [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

You can also use [trigger_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php):

```
<?php
if ($divisor == 0) {
    trigger_error("Cannot divide by zero", E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```